# Mapping list elements without using Table function

Tags: list-manipulation, map

How could I generate the following list of points using some function or mapping without using the table function.

```
x = (1 - Cos[# Pi])/2 & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1];
y = (1 - Cos[# Pi])/2 & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1];

nx = Length[x];
ny = Length[y];

nodesElement = 
      Flatten[Table[{{x[[i]], y[[j]]}, {x[[i + 1]], y[[j]]}, {x[[i + 1]], 
          y[[j + 1]]}, {x[[i]], y[[j + 1]]}}, {j, 1, ny - 1}, {i, 1, 
         nx - 1}], 1];
```

I am interested in more pure functional programming

Comment: One way: `Flatten[Outer[{y, x} |-> {{x[[1]], y[[1]]}, {x[[2]], y[[1]]}, {x[[2]], y[[2]]}, {x[[1]], y[[2]]}}, Partition[y, 2, 1], Partition[x, 2, 1], 1], 1]`

Comment: if you instead wanted a different order of the points you could maybe use `Tuples` instead of a custom function—or maybe there's a slicker way I'm not thinking of!

Comment: Is the order of your element important?

Comment: No. The order of the elements is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one: `Tuples /@ Tuples[Partition[x, 2, 1], 2]`

Or in the case $x\neq y$: `Tuples /@ Tuples[{Partition[x, 2, 1], Partition[y, 2, 1]}]`

Note that this gives the same thing as

```
Flatten[Table[{{x[[i]], y[[j]]}, {x[[i]], y[[j+1]]}, {x[[i+1]], 
    y[[j]]}, {x[[i+1]], y[[j+1]]}}, {i, 1, ny - 1}, {j, 1, nx - 1}], 1]
```

Which is just a reordering of what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Using RotateLeft and MapThread:

```
xv = Indexed[x, #] & /@ Range[5]
yv = Indexed[y, #] & /@ Range[5]

MapThread[{{#1, #2}, {#3, #2}, {#3, #4}, {#1, #4}} &, {xv, yv, 
  RotateLeft[xv], RotateLeft[yv]}]
```

That wraps around, you can use Most for a finite set of quads.